# Поле типа DateTime в модели и в представлении

Tags: c#, html5, asp.net-mvc

У меня есть некий класс модели:

```
public class SomeCreateModel
{
    ...

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [Display(Name = "Date time")]
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

И строго типизированное представление для создания объектов этого класса:

```
<div class="editor-label">
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateTime)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateTime)
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateTime)
</div>
```

При просмотре страницы в браузерах отображается элемент `<input type="datetime">`, однако браузеры отображают его как обычный элемент для ввода строки (т.е. нет выпадающего календаря для выбора даты и времени). `<!DOCTYPE html>` указан.

Также заметил, что при вводе в этот элемент, скажем, значения `16.06.2015` появляется сообщение о том, что введенное значение должно являться датой (хотя оно ей и является, но видимо `16` считается номером месяца).

Вопросы:

1. Почему данный элемент в браузере отображается как элемент для ввода строки, а не даты и времени, хотя имеет атрибут `type="datetime"`;
2. Почему при вводе значения в это поля, появляется сообщение о неверном вводе.

Answer (score 1):

> Почему при вводе значения в это поля, появляется сообщение о неверном вводе.

Нужно локализацию указывать. По-умолчанию дата идет mm/dd/yyyy